# Cosmos DB scaling costs

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

My understanding is that Cosmos DB RU/s are charged on a hourly basis.  If you scale up you're charged the increased rate for the hour.  But when does the hour begin?  From the moment you scale up or down or from the top of the hour?  Does anyone have a good answer?

Comment: Any collection created will be charged for a minimum of 1 hour. If I create a collection for 1 minute than delete it, I'll be charged an hour. If I create 3 collections for a minute each I'll be charged 3 hrs Here's a [Github comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node/blob/15cf138373beb86b9678e5cb4d09ad2c2fe1fb34/samples/Partitioning/app.js#L34-L37) from an Azure library verifying this. I get this doesn't exactly cover your question but I think it is helpful to be aware of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cosmos-db/) say:

> If you increase provisioned throughput at 9:30 AM from 400 RU/s to
>   1,000 RU/s and then lower provisioned throughput at 10:45 AM back to
>   400 RU/s, you will be charged for two hours of 1,000 RU/s.
>
> If you increase provisioned throughput for a container or a set of
>   containers at 9:30 AM from 100K RU/s to 200K RU/s and then lower
>   provisioned throughput at 10:45 AM back to 100K RU/s, you will be
>   charged for two hours of 200K RU/s.

Comment: Is it UTC time?